# HTML Select Tag text

Tags: html, html-select

I am trying to make a website about countries and I try to make it so that once you select a country it displays information about the country. Heres what I have:

```
<select>
<option selected disabled>Table of context</option>
<option value="1">Canada</option>
<option value="2">Finland</option>
<option value="3">Australia</option>
<option value="4">China</option>
<option value="5">Brazil</option>
<option value="5">Sweden</option>
```

I would like to make it so that once I select for an example Brazil, it displays some info about Brazil. And when I select Finland it displays info about Finland. But I havent figured out how to do this and couldnt find any info. Could anyone help?

Comment: is this info in a database?

Comment: Have you tried anything using JS or jQuery to achieve your requirements? Can you paste that code too here?

Answer (score 0):

try an [onchange function for select elemnt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery and hidden divs to display your information.

Here is a demo that uses your countries select element:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.Countries').hide(); 
    $('#countrySelect').change(function(){
    var countryVal = $('#countrySelect').val()
        if($('#countrySelect').val() != '') {
         $('.Countries').hide(); 
            $('#'+ countryVal).show(); 
        } else {
         $('.Countries').hide(); 
        } 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id=countrySelect>
<option selected disabled>Table of context</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Finland">Finland</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
</select>
<div id='Canada' class='Countries'>
Text about Canada .....
</div>
<div id='Finland' class='Countries'>
Text about Finland .....
</div>
<div id='Australia' class='Countries'>
Text about Australia .....
</div>
<div id='China' class='Countries'>
Text about China .....
</div>
<div id='Brazil' class='Countries'>
Text about Brazil .....
</div>
<div id='Sweden' class='Countries'>
Text about Sweden .....
</div>
```